# Help On Dual Amplifier Design

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, speakers, basic

I am pretty new to electronics and so far, have been teaching myself and designing things with the help of the internet. I made and designed a class-AB amplifier circuit that drives two 8-ohm speakers and unfortunately ran into some problems.

[image]

The amps (2x) used are the [LM875M](https://www.ti.com/product/LM4875). When applying 5v to the USB and playing audio, only one speaker (right side) is working. The same is for when plugging in headphones the Audio Out jack. Three other flaws include strong clipping when driving the speaker, the speaker being very quiet compared to the higher impendence headphones used, and the potentiometer seeming to only effect audio levels mid-turn and on. [This](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/PDB182-K220K-103B/2564759) is the potentiometer I purchased, and [This](https://www.visaton.de/sites/default/files/dd_product/frws5_8.pdf) is the Speaker used.

Much help on the schematic, components used, and other general information would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the default for USB 2 is half an amp at 5 V. Is that what you planned around? What's the voltage output of your selected regulator and its current compliance? (I'm ignoring the "only one speaker is working" bit for now.)

Comment: 'only one speaker is working' is excellent news for debugging, because it means you have a good side and a bad side to compare. Get comparing!

Comment: The channels look identical in the diagram but for a curious `tip` label in the top one: the difference should be in implementation (including components).

Comment: @periblepsis The regulator used is the BD450M2FP3-CE2, which to my knowledge, outputs 5 volts at 200mA, which should be enough power to drive both amplifiers. Another question on my mind is if both amps are supposed to share a common ground. Thanks.

Comment: May I ask why there is a regulator between the USB connector and the amplifier? Do you want to limit the current? There will be a voltage drop of around 0.5 V across the regulator.

Comment: @GlennKrause Jens makes a valid comment. The regulator cannot regulate 5 V out from 5 V in. It's an LDO but they don't have that low of a dropout! Also, if you are shooting for the maximum of 750 mW output to your speakers, this is a peak of about sqrt(2*0.75/8) or 433 mA and +/-3.5 V. That's at the speaker. The class-AB, while more efficient than class-A, still burns off the same power as the speaker. That's just one, not both speaker systems. I'm not saying you run the volume at max. But if you did...? Perhaps write more about your goals? (Also, headphones are very low power.)

Comment: @periblepsis Would it be logical to get rid of the regulator because of the voltage drop-off you mentioned? I'm wondering if running it at lower power would affect the schematic as a whole or just limit it until the second IC. Correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @GlennKrause An early thing you need to do is balance your own desire for audio volume with the power supply options you have. Headphones are easy. They are just "very low power" devices. But they have a range of impedance that you need to consider. Speakers need more power as they go into open air. The design power rating for music should be about 6 times the expected average need because of the dynamic range music typically requires. But voice is a whole different thing. You start at the transducers (mics, speakers, headphones) and work from both ends towards the middle.

Comment: @GlennKrause The reason for doing it that way is that the entire point of an audio system is to work with the meat-matter/biology of humans. It's not about electronics, so much. It's about having a desired outcome where things meet up with the human body. The electronics is mostly just a consequence of those decisions. So the transducers are everything and the electronics simply "flows out from there." One must have a very firm grip on the human factors part, first.

Comment: @GlennKrause That's why it's difficult to tell you about getting rid of the regulator. Or whether or not the USB power source is sufficient, itself. We'd need to know a lot more about your goals (human-wise.) Do you need ***both*** headphones and speaker support? Do you expect to play music with this system? What kinds of input sources must be supported? If speakers, then what volume levels are required (what sound pressures at the human ear and at what distances and orientations?) Or you could just say "USB power only -- what can I achieve with only that supply?"

Comment: @GlennKrause But for educational purposes, just get rid of the regulator and use the USB supply, directly. You can get up to 500 mA from it, I believe, or 2.5 watts. There are two ways to go with the amplifier: bridged or single-ended. Bridged will make better use of your 5 V supply rail and allow you to deliver more power to the speakers (still limited by the USB, though.) Single-ended you might get 1.5 V peak (3 V pp) into the 8 Ohm speaker or perhaps as much as 150 mW per speaker. Bridged, more than twice that, or perhaps 500 mW. Both within USB capability.